# mvn war:war without copying resources

Tags: maven, war

I have a file in a Maven project that need to be obsfuscated. At the moment I:

1. Clean/build the project;
2. Open an eternal application to obsfuscate the file in the `/target/ROOT/blah` folder;

I then want to run `mvn war:war` but it always copies the resources folder back into the `/target/ROOT` folder which overwrites the obsfuscated file.

MVN output

```
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [core] in [core\target\ROOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [src\main\webapp] <= I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM
Webapp assembled in [22812 msecs]
Building war: target\ROOT.war
```

I have tried the following and a few variations:

```
<profile>
        <id>war-only</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceExcludes>**</warSourceExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

OK got it eventually:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/null</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Setting `warSourceDirectory` to any non-existant directory meant it didn't copy anything in.